# How to hide a div after complete the ajax call,my code is given below ..in this code div hide before the refresh

Tags: javascript, ajax

How to hide a div after complete the ajax call,my code is given below... in this code div hide before the refresh

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search-button').click(function() {
        $('#imgLoader').show();
        var request = $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'response.php',
            data: $('#search-form').serialize(),
            success: function(response) {
                var url = 'detail_page.php';
                $('#my_cart').load(url + ' #mycart');
                $('#refcart').load(url + ' #shoppingCart');
                $('#imgLoader').hide();
            }
        })
    });
});
```

image loader hide before complete the refresh of two divs. Please help me

Comment: The jQuery-load function got a complete function as a parameter. You could setup to hide your imgLoader after completion.

Comment: What do you mean by `complete the refresh`

Comment: may be he means complete of loading.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/load/

You can add a callback to the .load methods that will trigger once the element is fully loaded.

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html", function() {
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

In your case, something like that:

```
 $('#my_cart').load(url + ' #mycart', function () {
   $('#imgLoader').hide();
 );
```

Comment: one of the loads might take more time..this is not complete solution

Comment: Agreed, Wa Kai answer might be more complete :)

Comment: Or the one from Gueras Arnaud or Yury Tarabanko

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution could be by using the complete parameter of load:

```
success: function(response) {
    var url = 'detail_page.php';
    $('#my_cart').load(url + ' #mycart', function() {
        $('#refcart').load(url + ' #shoppingCart', function() {
            $('#imgLoader').hide();
         });
    });
}
```

Keep in mind, thats not the best solution, because the second load will be executed not until the completion of the first.

Edit:
I would suggest you to work with `tokens`:

```
success: function(response) {
    var myCartLoaded = false;
    var refCartLoaded = false;
    var url = 'detail_page.php';
    $('#my_cart').load(url + ' #mycart', function() {
        myCartLoaded = true;
        if(refCartLoaded) { 
            $('#imgLoader').hide();
            myCartLoaded = false;
            refCartLoaded = false;
        } 
    });
    $('#refcart').load(url + ' #shoppingCart', function() {
        refCartLoaded = true;
        if(myCartLoaded) { 
            $('#imgLoader').hide();
            myCartLoaded = false;
            refCartLoaded = false;
        } 
    });
}
```

This way both load-functions will start at the same time and the one which stops last will trigger to hide your imageLoader.

Comment: Ah, sweet callback hell :)

Answer (score 2):

You have more than one error in your code :

- You make an ajax request to get search result, but you don't use the
  `response` inside the success function. `$().load` is async, that
- means you should wait the end of each `$().load` request before
  hiding `#imgLoader`

The $().load is working like this

> .load( url [, data ] [, complete ] )

And you should use promises to make it work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search-button').click(function() {
        $('#imgLoader').show();
        // create the deffered instances
        var myCartDeferred = $.Deferred();
        var refCartDeffered = $.Deferred();

        // $.ajax also return a deffered
        var request = $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'response.php',
            data: $('#search-form').serialize(),
            success: function(response) {
                var url = 'detail_page.php';

                $('#imgLoader').hide();
            }
        })

        // Setup the chain of events
        $.when(myCartDeferred, refCartDefferd, request).then(function() {
            alert('done');
        });

        // start the load actions at the same time than the $.ajax and pass the deferred.resolve as complete param
        $('#my_cart').load(url + ' #mycart', myCartDeferred.resolve);
        $('#refcart').load(url + ' #shoppingCart', refCartDeffered.resolve);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery `.load` returns jquery object making it inconvenient to wait for multiple loads to happen. You could add custom `promiseToLoad` method that returns a promise.

**NB! Haven't tested this code.**

```
$.fn.promiseToLoad = function(url, data) {
    var dfd = $.Deferred(),
        jquery = this;
    jquery.load(url, data, function() {
        if(dfd.state() === 'pending') {
            dfd.resolveWith(jquery, jquery);
        }
    });
    return dfd.promise();
}
```

and then

```
var myCart = $('#my_cart').promiseToLoad(url + ' #mycart'),
    refCart = $('#refcart').promiseToLoad(url + ' #shoppingCart');

$.when(myCart, refCart).then(function() {
    $('#imgLoader').hide();
});
```